# Can not deduce proper type when coercing newtype

Tags: haskell, coerce

I was trying to simplify my life with `newtype` with `coerce`, but I've encountered a quite painful problem when using it in certain scenario:

```hs
import Data.Coerce (coerce)
import Data.Foldable (toList)

-- | newtype instance wrapping foldable type (not necessary [Int])
newtype Foo = Foo [Int]

bar :: [Int]
bar = toList $ coerce $ Foo [1,2,3]
```

This fails as Haskell is not able to deduce the type correctly.

**Is there a way to force this to be correctly resolved?** (without directly specifying what coerce should coerce into) Or maybe there is other clean solution? (SO answers suggest mostly the coerce)

Comment: The `toList` makes no sense: this means that `coerce` should convert it to an certain `Foldable`, but it is never specified which one.

Comment: Probably coerce is to unversal for my case. I would expect it to convert to the fordable which newtype carry.

Comment: In one of the answer I saw some way of using lens to access it, but I can not find it.

Comment: Why not just remove the call to `toList`?

Answer (score 3):

The `lens` solution you may be looking for is in `Control.Lens.Wrapped`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric, StandaloneDeriving #-}

import Control.Lens
import Control.Lens.Wrapped
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Foldable (toList)

newtype Foo = Foo [Int] deriving (Generic)
instance Wrapped Foo

bar :: [Int]
bar = toList . view _Wrapped' $ Foo [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer is adding a field accessor:

```hs
type    Foo :: Type
newtype Foo = Foo { getFoo :: [Int] }

bar :: [Int]
bar = toList $ getFoo $ Foo [1,2,3]
```

which works even if you parameterise `Foo` by the `Foldable` structure:

```hs
-- >> toList $ getFoo $ Foo [1,2,3]
-- [1,2,3]
-- >> toList $ getFoo $ Foo Nothing
-- []
type    Foo :: (Type -> Type) -> Type
newtype Foo f = Foo { getFoo :: f Int }
```

If you do want guided `coerce` you can imagine a type family that resolves the underlying type. This is a standalone type family, unlike the associated `Wrapped` from the lens answer. I personally think this type family ought to be included in the standard library with instances magically generated by GHC.

```hs
type          Underlying :: Type -> Type
type family   Underlying a
type instance Underlying Foo = [Int]
type instance Underlying Any = Bool
type instance Underlying All = Bool
-- ..

underlying :: Coercible a (Underlying a) => a -> Underlying a
underlying = coerce

bar :: [Int]
bar = toList $ underlying $ Foo [1,2,3]
```

We don't need to define individual `underlying` unwrappings, all the definitions are `coerce`. You can now replace `coerce` with `underlying` which gives the compiler some guidance and it replaces `getFoo`; even in the parameterised case:

```
type instance Underlying (Foo f) = f Int

-- >> toList $ underlying $ Foo [1,2,3]
-- [1,2,3]
-- >> toList $ underlying $ Foo Nothing
-- []
```

Without the type family to tell what the target type is `coerce` is too general. There are arbitrarily many types coercible to/from `Foo`:

```hs
coerce
  :: Foo -> [Int]
  :: Foo -> Identity [Int]
  :: Foo -> Identity (Sum (Product (Alt Identity (Ap [] Int))))
  :: ..
```

I consider raw `coerce` appearing in code to be an anti-pattern because of this inference problem, and try to replace it with other abstractions like `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` or `DerivingVia` when I can.

That being said you are able to hold GHC's hand with `TypeApplications` where you explicitly specify the return type

```
>> toList $ coerce @_ @[Int] $ Foo [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
>> toList $ coerce @_ @(Maybe Int) $ Foo Nothing
[]
```

or specify the input type of `toList`

```hs
>> toList @[] @Int $ coerce $ Foo [1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
>> toList @Maybe @Int $ coerce $ Foo Nothing
[]
```

Comment: Link to `coercible-utils`! I had a lot of fun making extra magic happen there.